# Symfony2 + Twig: Using an entity type field to store unsaved entities

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've spent a while looking through the symfony2 docs trying to find a suitable method of doing what I need to do, maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.

Basically, I have an entity called `Album`, which can have many `Subalbums` associated with it. As the user is creating an `Album` entity using a form, I want them to be able to create quick `Subalbum` entities in-line, which will get saved later on. I also want to display the field in a custom format, so I don't want to use a `select` tag with a `multiple` attribute, instead I'm manually rendering it in Twig (I haven't had a problem with this).

The relationship on `Subalbum` is defined as follows:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Vhoto\AlbumBundle\Entity\Album")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $parent;
```

Here's what I've tried so far...

1. Use an `entity` type field in the form builder, and then manually output the field. The issue I have with using the `entity` field is that if the user creates a `Subalbum` inline, symfony2 doesn't like it when I submit the form because it has no ID.
2. Use a hidden field type and try submitting multiple entries under the same field name (`album[subalbums][]`). Symfony2 also doesn't like this when I submit the form

I guess I'm going to have to have a `prePersist` method in my `Album` entity to create any `Subalbum` entities that the user has created inline?

Hopefully there is a far more graceful solution that I'm just completely overlooking.

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a better way to do it.

**Entity creation**

Create the two `Entity` POPOs and assign a `many-to-one` relationship to one of the fields of the child entity (you have done this correctly). You might also want to define a `one-to-many` relationship in the parent

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Child", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"persist", "remove" }, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $children;
```

I am not sure if it's necessary, but you should explicitly set the relationship in your setters just to be sure. For example in your owning entity:

```
public function addChild(ChildInterface $child)
{
    if(!$this->hasChild($child))
    {
        $this->children->add($child);
        $child->setParent($this);
    }
}
```

`Doctrine` doesn't probably use these methods to bind the post data, but having this for yourself might take care of several persisting issues.

**Form type creation**

Create a form type for both entities

```
/**
 * This would be the form type for your sub-albums.
 */
class ChildType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        //$builder->add(...);
        //...
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Entity\Child'
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ChildType';
    }
}

/**
 * This would be the form type for your albums.
 */
class ParentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        // This part here describes the relationship between the two
        // form types.
        $builder->add('children', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new ChildType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ChildType';
    }
}
```

With the options `allow_add` and `allow_delete` you've effectively told Symfony, that a user can add or remove entities from the collection. The `prototype` option lets you have a prototype of the so-called sub-form on your page.

**Controller**

You should enforce the relationship here as well just to be safe. I have tucked this away in a separate entity manager layer (I have separate managers for more complicated entities), but you can most certainly do this in your controllers as well.

```
foreach($parent->getChildren() as $child)
{
    if($child->getParent() === NULL)
    {
        $child->setParent($parent);
    }
}
```

**View**

Prepare your form's template. The prototype should be rendered by calling `form_rest(form)` somewhere in your template. In case it doesn't or you'd like to customize the prototype, here's a sample of how to do it.

```html
<script id="ParentType_children_prototype" type="text/html">
    <li class="custom_prototype_sample">
        <div class="content grid_11 alpha">
            {{ form_widget(form.children.get('prototype').field1) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.children.get('prototype').field2) }}
            {{ form_rest(form.children.get('prototype') ) }}
        </div>
    </li>
</script>
```

You'd have to make the form dynamic by using JavaScript. If you use `jQuery`, you can access the prototype by calling `$('ParentType_children_prototype').html()`. It is important to replace all occurrences of `$$name$$` in the prototype with the proper index number when adding a new child to the parent.

I hope this helps.

**EDIT** I just noticed there's an [article in the Symfony2 Form Type reference](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/collection.html) about `CollectionType`. It has a nice alternative on how to implement the front-end for this.

Comment: what an awesome answer, I'm just going to work through implementing this now.. cheers

Comment: hmm, I get an error `Item "get" for "Array" does not exist`, which refers to the line `{{ form_widget(form.children.get('prototype').name) }}`. I have initialised my `subalbums` property in the constructor as an `ArrayCollection`, is that right?

Comment: ahh wait, I'm being stupid.. I didn't change `children` to `subalbums`